# Make a function that can search for words in a sentence and display many of them odd or even with regex?

Tags: python, regex, list, function

Count the number of the same word in a sentence, and count the same word whether odd or even use regex. For example

**Call:**

```
def words (sentence, findwords)

print ("I like cat cat", "cat")
```

**output:**

"even" (because of the word "cat" there are 2)

sorry but I tried to make my own program. But it says there is no calling string. So I want to ask which parts of my program that I need to correct or which are wrong?

```
import re

def words (sentence, findwords):

    sentence=re.search('\d+\.\d+.\s+',sentence)

    find=sentence.count()

    if find%2!=0:

        print("odd")

    else:

        print("even")


print(words("I like cat cat",("cat")))
```

Comment: can't you just do `"I like cat cat".count('cat')`

Comment: Well i tried, but still error

Comment: it's working for me, what is the error?

Comment: import re
def words(sentence, findwords):
    sentence=re.search('\d+\.\d+.\s+',sentence)
    find=sentence.count()
    if find%2!=0:
        print("odd")
    else:
        print("even")
print(words("I like cat cat".count('cat'),("cat")))

Comment: Sorry, the program here is irregular

Comment: Can I ask you sir ? Is my program using search not suitable?

Comment: your search is returning None

Comment: So it requires a return, but is it possible without doing a return?

Comment: i have edited your code

Comment: I understand now, that it must use returns. very clear explanation sir

Comment: Glat it helped. if your query is resolved, mark it as an answer. If it helped, upvote it.

Comment: I would like too, but my reputation less than 15

Comment: no worries, happy coding!

Comment: You so kind sir, happy coding to you too!

Answer (score 0):

```
def words (sentence, findwords): return sentence.count(findwords)

print(words("I like cat cat","cat"))
```

[image]

For your odd and even

```
def words (sentence, findwords): return "Even" if sentence.count(findwords)%2==0 else "Odd"

print(words("I like cat cat","cat"))
```

[image]

Fixing your code

```
import re

def words (sentence, findwords):

    sentence=re.findall('(\b[^\s]+\b)',sentence) #finding all words

    find=sentence.count(findwords) #finding your word in those words

    if find%2!=0:

        return("odd")

    else:

        return("even")


print(words("I like cat cat","cat"))
```